# Get hold of Spring model from everywhere

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a controller I can get model by declaring Model/ModelMap typed parameter. In handler interceptors and in view rendering I get the same. But how do I get the model from the arbitrary class, which can get hold of ApplicationContext or web request? I just don't want to use model.addAttribute() all the time and would like my service automatically put objects into model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you shouldn't. Your controllers are the entry point of your application, so you get them there, and pass them as arguments to the layers below.

Comment: Well, what I do now is that in every controller method I call something like myService.use(model) and that is becomming boilerplate.

Comment: Indeed - you should pass only the parameters that the service needs. For example `myService.calculate(modelMap.get("basePrice"), modelMap.get("discount"))`